# Rules for struct aligntment

Tags: c++, struct, memory-alignment

Consider the code:

```
struct A
{
    char b;
    bool a;
    double c;
};

struct B
{
    char b;
    double c;
    bool a;
};

int main()
{
    std::cout << sizeof(A) << '\n'; // 16
    std::cout << sizeof(B) << '\n'; // 24
}
```

Whats happening here ?
What are purposes in a second case to be aligned by a 8 bytes ??

(OS: windows 7 32 bit)

Comment: Try it on paper. Consider that the compiler can't reorganize those members.

Comment: `double` requires 8-byte alignment. Remember that `sizeof` includes the padding.

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/object#Alignment